How to enable/disable vibrate programmatically in inner app
private void setNotification(String reminderTitle, String reminderId) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(SharePrefUtils.getString(Constant_ad.currentNotificationId, "0"));
        num++;
        SharePrefUtils.putString(Constant_ad.currentNotificationId, String.valueOf(num));

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
        Log.e("getVibrateStatus", SharePrefUtils.getBoolean(Constant_ad.IS_VIBRATE, false) + "");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, getString(R.string.channel_name)
                    , NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(getString(R.string.channel_description));
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            if (SharePrefUtils.getBoolean(Constant_ad.IS_VIBRATE, false)){
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            }
//            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(SharePrefUtils.getBoolean(Constant_ad.IS_VIBRATE, false));
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_ctitle))
                .setContentText(reminderTitle);

        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, RemindersActivity.class);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("type", "notificationData");
        notifyIntent.putExtra("id", reminderId);
        notifyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        int contentIntentFlags = PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            contentIntentFlags |= PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.parseInt(SharePrefUtils.getString(Constant_ad.currentNotificationId, "0"))
                , notifyIntent, contentIntentFlags);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(SharePrefUtils.getString(Constant_ad.currentNotificationId, "0"))
                , notificationBuilder.build());
    }

Here is my notification function.

In general, you cannot change a notification channel once you create it.

so is possible for manage on off vibration from the app for notification? or there any way to implement this?

Generally, users should control things like that through the Settings app. The idea is that your notification channels should be based on role (e.g., timer alerts, marketing messages), and users can then tailor how they appear in Settings.

okay but i saw one reminder app in play store, in this app user can manage on off vibrate in inner app. so how they did this? thanks
